# Request for "state-of-matter" tag

Tags: support, tags

Coming across some chemistry questions, I realized many had to do with matter or specifically the state of matter of a substance, not only does this affect multiple properties in chemistry, but this links with intermediate questions lodging between this and physics.

Many questions that I and I believe many other users will have may spawn within this tag. However I do not have the privilege to make a new tag... so here I request it.

Comment: Just use the phase tag ?

Comment: Perhaps someone can create 'state of matter' as a synonym for phase?

Comment: Ah yes, I guess a phase tag may be what I'd be looking for, perhaps I overlooked at this tag as I was searching for a tag that had more to do with materials by Jahn-Teller distortion or other lab-conditioned states which would be kinda controversial to label as phases (That transits into other states by temperature or pressure.).